# Is it possible to use bpy in python scripting without Blender app open?

Tags: python

I'm trying to automate the process of rotating multiple NIFTI 3D file and taking screenshots of that rotation using bpy, but WITHOUT blender app itself open.

Not sure whether it will work however...

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: No.  But it is possible to run Blender without opening the user interface and use [command line arguments](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) to invoke the python script.

Comment: To be more precise, you could build Blender as a module for another program and use bpy from the modular blender in that program, but for your purpose, it would be a lot easier to invoke a script from the command line.